# Prevent PHP from opening documents above documentroot

Tags: php, permissions, document-root

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

My php script can currently open files above the document root by using relative paths such as require_once(../../passowrds.php);

1)is there anyway to enforce absolute paths open above the document root?

2)what is the safest method of accessing files above the document root?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "above document root mean"

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie The "document root" is the directory pointed to by the webserver, which might be "/var/www/myapp/htdocs"; "above" that lie the directories "/var/www/myapp", "/var/www", "/var" and "/". (And also, implicitly, children of those, such as "/var/www/someonelsesapp")

Comment: It would be useful to have some background to your scenario: are you intending to allow non-trusted users to upload their own PHP files, and want to restrict the code they can run? If so, have you considered that they would also be able to run `file_get_contents` or similar and "steal" the code that way?

Comment: users will not be uploading code, just running my current scripts.

Comment: The way i setup my site is to have multiple include files. This enables me to keep non trivial code in the document root but keep sensitive documents above the root.

Comment: Unless 1) your site itself has already been hacked 2) you're allowing anybody but yourself to define the path to a file in your filesystem to be `include()`'d or `require()`'d by direct input, you have nothing to worry about (concerning what you're asking).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Safest method for require file in write **$a = 'samplevalue';** and top of the which passowrds.php in write;
**if($a != 'samplevalue'){ header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); }**
**passowrds.php :**

```
if($r_key != 'a23b24c25samplekey' or empty($r_key)){ header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); exit(); } // r_key not equal a23b24c25samplekey or empty forward main page
bla.. bla.. bla..
```

**sample.php :**

```
  $r_key = 'a23b24c25samplekey';
  require_once(../../passowrds.php);
```

and that can be used for relative path;

```
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/yourfolder/passowrwds.php";
   require_once($path);
```

require_once(../../passowrds.php); safest than $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
       $path .= "/yourfolder/passowrwds.php";
       require_once($path);

Comment: Thanks, I think this should help

Comment: I have no idea what problem this answer is supposed to be addressing.  Put another way, I don't see what this achieves.

Comment: your if goal is prevent access to include file out root ;
Create an empty index of all directories.
Thus, without knowing the name of the file can not access the file.
also if you use to above key system important files such as index.php the user can not access. I'm sorry I did not help.My English it a little weak. 
Good day.

Answer (score -1):

> is there anyway to enforce absolute paths open above the document root?

I interpret this to mean "is it possible to prevent above-docroot-access with relative paths?".  The answer is: Not that I know of, short of manually validating the path string (look for excessive ".." etc.)

> what is the safest method of accessing files above the document root?

It depends on your definition of "safest"; what is your scenario where this could ever cause a problem?

However, a good start would be to validate any user input that controls this, rather that simply doing e.g. `require_once($_GET["file"])`.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie: It's intended as an answer (albeit an incomplete one).

Comment: @JmsBnd: Ok, but what is your concern that leads you to ask this question?

Comment: I am trying to prevent a situation where a user hacks my site by and uses relative paths to access password documents

Comment: @JmsBnd: If a user "hacks" your site in the sense that they can access your PHP code, then it's already too late.

Comment: I guess thats true. Just checking there are not further requirements needed to keep it safe